# can I split some text on python?

Tags: python, text, split

I want to split text on python and take some part, for example:

`let the blue sky meet the blue sea`

I want this for the result:

`blue sky`

this is my code

```py
text = "let the blue sky meet the blue sea"
bluee = text.split("the", 1)[1]
print bluee
```

and the result from the code is
`blue sky meet the blue sea`

Comment: `bluee = text.split("the")[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would strip away the beggining of the text and then the last of the text.
`raw_input()` or `input()` could be used to have the user determine what part of the code to be stripped out

```
text = "let the blue sky meet the blue sea"
bluee = text.split("the", 1)[1]
skyy = bluee.split("meet", 1)[0]
print skyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think understanding split syntax will help us.

text.split(sep, max): (both sep and max are optional)

sep: the way you want to separate your text (default is space)

max: the maximum number of group you want to split (default is -1, it means all groups)

---

Here is in your case:

```
 text = "let the blue sky meet the blue sea"
## short answer
print(' '.join(text.split()[2:4]))
```

Explanation

We will do 3 steps

```
# split it by default
list_word = text.split() # return ['let', 'the', 'blue', 'sky', 'meet', 'the', 'blue', 'sea']
# then we choose from 3rd to 4th elements
target_word = list_word[2:4] # return ['blue', 'sky']
# connect all element together with space
result = ' '.join(target_word)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 text = "let the blue sky meet the blue sea"
 text=text.split(" ")
 text=text[2]+" "+text[3]
 print(text)
```

Comment: Please add some comments

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "let the blue sky meet the blue sea"
text=text.split()
```

You don't need any arguments here as split defaults to whitespace

```
result = ' '.join(text[2:])
print(result)
```

Using .join is faster and is more pythonic than the + operator